# Is it possible to have histogram in LogLog scale?

Tags: histograms, logarithmic-scale

`Histogram[data,"Log"]` will generate an histogram with a log scale on the `x` axis, but I need a `LogLog` scale, is it possible?

Comment: Naively, I would just take the log of the y-values before you make the histogram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the form `Histogram[data, {"Log", bspec}, {"Log", hspec}]`, where
`{"Log", bspec}` *applies binning bspec on log-transformed data*, and `{"Log", hspec}` gives *log-transformed height specification*.

**Example:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[LogNormalDistribution[10, 1], 1000];

Histogram[data,{"Log", 10}, {"Log", "Count"}]
```

[image]

Compare with

```
Histogram[data, 10, "Count"]
```

[image]